# Which modern languages have more than two grammatical categories for numbers?

Tags: list-of-languages, grammatical-number

As stated in the title. I aware that some languages have some remnants of dual grammtical numbers.

Comment: Not just remnants, but full dual and sometimes triad systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are also languages that have more than singular, dual, plural. A good overview is provided by Corbett 2000, which is an really good overview over the category of Number in general. Here are some examples he gives (§ 2.2):

- Languages with the **trial** (for “three”): Larike (Central Moluccan), Ngan’gityemerri (Daly), Marrithiyel (Daly), Anindilyakwa (the language of Groote Eyland)
- Languages with **paucal** (for “small numbers”): Bayso, Yimas, Boumaa Fijian, Paamese, Manam, Ambrym

It is a controversial question if there is a true *quadral* (for “four) -- and some languages also have special encoding for “large numbers” though there is a lot of variation going on. The wikipedia article on [grammatical number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_number) is also quite good.

#### Literature

Corbett, Greville G. 2000. *Number.* Cambridge: Cambridge University Press.

Answer (score 0):

For a language with a large speaker base, Arabic has the dual. You can easily find more examples here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_%28grammatical_number%29